# Haskell declaring an instance of Show class

Tags: class, haskell, instance, show

I am trying to wrap my mind around classes and data structures in Haskell, specifically declaring a type instance of it. I can get it to work with some classes and data types but not all of them so I must be missing something. Specifically I have the following data declaration:

```
data LinkedList a = End | Link a (LinkedList a)
```

I want to declare an instance of Show for that type so that the output looks something close to "el1, el2, el3, el4, ..."

```
instance Show LinkedList where
    show (End) = "."
    show (Link a b) = show a ++ "," ++ show b
```

As expected this doesn't work... Any idea why? I think I understand what "data" and "type" mean but I am not sure whether I am comfortable with classes and instances. Thank you

Comment: What error do you get? Please [edit] your question to include this important detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
instance Show LinkedList where
```

`LinkedList` is not a type, `LinkedList a` is a type. Correcting that, we get

```
instance Show (LinkedList a) where
```

Then , we get another error because we call `show` on values of type `a`. We need to require that `a` belongs to class `Show`, too.

```
instance Show a => Show (LinkedList a) where
```

This should now work.

Comment: Thank you! So why isn't LinkedList a type?

Comment: @OmarKahol Beacuse it lacks an argument. It is a constructor of kind `* -> *`, i.e. (roughly) a function from types to types, and we need to pass it an argument to get a type.

Comment: @OmarKahol LinkedList is a "type-level function" which produces types. It's not a type in the same way that `(* 5)` isn't a number, but if you pass it a number you get a number back.

Comment: @OmarKahol: You can learn more about kinds with the `:kind` command in GHCi. `:kind Show` gives `* -> Constraint` because `Show` is a typeclass that takes a type of kind `*` (a “base type”, one that contains values) and returns a constraint; `:kind LinkedList` gives `* -> *` because `LinkedList` is a *type constructor* that takes a type of kind `*` and produces a type, also of kind `*`. So you can’t write `Show LinkedList` because `*` and `* -> *` don’t match—it’s a kind error, which is like a type error at the type level. `*` can also be written as `Type` (imported from `GHC.Types`).